# Attiny84 with external eeprom-write and read beyond 255

Tags: attiny, eeprom

Just starting with external EEPROM and ATTiny's.  I am successfully writing and reading to the 24LC64 chip using the following code with TinyWireM (thanks to other help on the forums). However, I really need to store integers up to 8500.
I'm assuming I need to store the number as 2 bytes and reassemble them when needed, just dont have the knowledge yet to do so.  Any help is truly appreciated...

```
    //------------------I2C EEPROM-----------------------
void writeAddress(int address, int val)
{
  TinyWireM.beginTransmission(EEPROM_I2C_ADDRESS);
  TinyWireM.send(address >> 8);   // MSB
  TinyWireM.send(address & 0xFF); // LSB
  TinyWireM.send(val);
  TinyWireM.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

byte readAddress(int address)
{
  byte rdata = 0xFF;
  
  TinyWireM.beginTransmission(EEPROM_I2C_ADDRESS); 
  TinyWireM.send(address >> 8);   // MSB
  TinyWireM.send(address & 0xFF); // LSB
  TinyWireM.endTransmission();  
  TinyWireM.requestFrom(EEPROM_I2C_ADDRESS, 2);  

 if (TinyWireM.available())
  {
    rdata = TinyWireM.receive();
  }
  return rdata;
}
```

Comment: You are already sending a 2-byte memory address to the EEPROM. It should work to do the same operations with the value to save. Research about the bitwise operators, especially the shift operator `>>`, the AND operator `&` and the OR operator `|`.

Comment: Thats the frustrating part of it.  I totally get that and I actually now am able to send the two bytes to the two registers.  I just cant figure out the TinyWireM syntax to read the values from the 2nd address.  I'm looking for a way to tell ask for the data in (address + 1 & 0xFF) and I keep getting the data from the only the first address.

Comment: @VinnyP this site is not a forum ... all of what you said in a comment belongs in the question at the top of this page ... please edit your question and then delete the comment

Comment: You asked for two bytes of data with `TinyWireM.requestFrom(EEPROM_I2C_ADDRESS, 2);`, but your function and your `rdata` is a `byte` instead of an `int`, and you only get one byte with `TinyWireM.receive();`.